# jQuery remove specific fields

Tags: jquery

Hello I have this function that will delete all the empty fields in the form:

```
 $('input:text[value=""]', '#submForm').remove();
```

But as I said it will remove ALL the empty fields.

I need instead to check and remove only specific Fields with a Specific ID.

How do I change this function to remove only the the Fields I want and not every field in the form?

**EDIT:**
Not specific Fields by using each ID of each Field. But all the Fields that are inside a Specific DIV id.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the relevant html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend your selector like this:

```
$('div#someID input:text[value=""]', '#submForm').remove();
```

(assuming that the div is also a descendant of #submForm)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divid").children().remove();
```